# ElasticSearch with Docker - Enable Anonymous Access

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

For local development, I want to run an ElasticSearch (5.5.2) container using Docker, but I don't want to have to deal with authentication.

I have read https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/5.5/anonymous-access.html, and it seems that the container comes with X-Pack which adds security (requiring a username and password).

Previously I have been running:

```
docker run -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" --name es docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.5.
```

How can I allow anonymous access?

Answer (score 2):

Add the environmental variable `xpack.security.enabled=false` to the `docker run` command.

Complete command:

```
docker run -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" -e "xpack.security.enabled=false" --name es docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.5.2
```

Reference: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-do-i-disable-x-pack-security-on-the-elasticsearch-5-2-2-docker-image/78183/4